# innerHTML doesn't work immediately when using function to change value

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Title may not be perfectly clear, but I try to explain my problem using example.
I have function which may take quite some time to execute, so I want to notify user when this function is executing. I want to show notification when the function is starting and delete it when function ended.
This approach works exactly how I want:

```
function foo()
{
   var r = document.getElementById('id');
   r.innerHTML = 'processing...';
   reallyLongFoo();
   r.innerHTML = 'done!';
}
```

But I prefer to change notification by another function. Like that:

```
function foo()
{
   changeInfo('processing...');
   reallyLongFoo();
   changeInfo('done!');
}
function changeInfo(info)
{
   var r = document.getElementById('id');
   r.innerHTML = info;
}
```

However this version isn't  working correctly. Value 'result' isn't changing  until function ends and it goes directly to 'done!', skipping 'processing...'

I'm guessing that both changInfo Functions are executed after foo. How to force them to be executed immediately?

Comment: I guess you will have to show what is this `reallyLongFoo`.

Comment: Can you post all your code please?

Comment: What is the function reallyLongFoo() defination?

Comment: Should I? I mean, I could, but there is a really long code, and it's not messing around with document's structure.
You can reproduce this situation simply putting a long for-loop inside reallyLongFoo - it acts the same.

Comment: @user1677734, See my [answer here](http://pastebin.com/5E6deVWZ)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below by adding a callback.

```
function foo()
{
   changeInfo('processing...');
   reallyLongFoo(function() {
      changeInfo('done!');
   });

}
function changeInfo(info)
{
   var r = document.getElementById('id');
   r.innerHTML = info;
}

function reallyLongFoo(callback)
{
   //Put all your codes

   callback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mate, you can use jquery promise or something similar to achieve this, but it's not that nice, they are not natively implemented, the best thing you can do is make the second changeInfo as a call back on your long foo, just call it after you done the dom manipulation.

when you putting two method call in one method, no matter how long it takes, they execute and returns, but inside one method, all the single line of code executes in sync mode.

```
    function foo()
{
   changeInfo('processing...');
   reallyLongFoo(function() {
      changeInfo('done!');
   });

}
function changeInfo(info)
{
   var r = document.getElementById('id');
    r.innerHTML = info;
}

function reallyLongFoo(callback)
{
   //Put all your codes

   callback();
}
```

Just reference Deepak's code, but same idea！